# Get perpendicular to line from point

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry

So I have a line that rotates constantly and I want to have another line to be perpendicular to the rotating line. The problem is that it will occasionally point the perpendicular (yellow) line away from my rotating line (white). The math is done inside the function and the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGCB1.gif). I would like the two lines to intersect sooner or later if lengthened. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def perpendicular_finder(line, point):
    x1, y1 = line[0]
    x2, y2 = line[1]
    x3, y3 = point
    if ((y2 - y1) ^ 2 + (x2 - x1) ^ 2) !=0:
        k = ((y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1)) / ((y2 - y1) ^ 2 + (x2 - x1) ^ 2)
        x4 = x3 - k * (y2 - y1)
        y4 = y3 + k * (x2 - x1)
        x4 = np.int(x4)
        y4 = np.int(y4)

        return x4,y4


ballCircle = (200, 200)
purBall = (540,300)
cueX1 = 200
cueY1 = 200
cueX2 = 400
cueY2 = 400
count = 0
while True:
    if count < 400:
        cueX2 -= 1
    elif count < 800:
        cueY2 -= 1
    elif count < 1200:
        cueX2 += 1
    else:
        cueY2 += 1
    if count == 1600:
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1

    blank = np.zeros((500, 900, 3), np.uint8)  # Create canvas the size of table

    kek = perpendicular_finder((ballCircle, (cueX2,cueY2)), purBall)

    cv2.line(blank, purBall, kek, (0, 255, 255), 1)  # good path
    cv2.circle(blank, ballCircle, 10, (255, 255, 255), -1)  # Ball
    cv2.circle(blank, purBall, 10, (0, 255, 255), -1)  # Purple Ball
    cv2.arrowedLine(blank, (cueX1, cueY1), (cueX2, cueY2), (255, 255, 255), 3)  # Cue

    cv2.imshow("kk", blank)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Edit 1: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osKHb.gif) is what user MBo recommended.

Comment: Well, look at this logically right. If you 2 rotating lines on a plane there's no way they could stay perpendicular to each other at all times. What's happening here is the second point B is indeed being perpendicular. The way it found to do so is by warping to the other end of your screen, much like when you play a game of snake. go down and you come out at the top

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too sure that this is absolutely correct since the yellow line jumps when the white line reaches a new quadrant each time.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function for calculation of projection point

```
def proj(x1, y1, x2, y2, xp, yp):
    x12 = x2 - x1
    y12 = y2 - y1
    dotp = x12 * (xp - x1) + y12 * (yp - y1)
    dot12 = x12 * x12 + y12 * y12
    if dot12:
        coeff = dotp / dot12
        lx = x1 + x12 * coeff
        ly = y1 + y12 * coeff
        return lx, ly
    else:
        return None
```

Seems you have occasionally used  `xor` operator here: `^ 2` instead of squaring `**2`

Note that your function looses right direction, while mine projects point correctly for any angle (grey line is backward continuation of arrow)

[ideone](https://ideone.com/mr4vQR)

[How it looks](https://ibb.co/VMWfjfN)

Comment: I'm afraid to say that this did not produce the results I wanted. I will add a gif of what happens with this code with an edit.

Comment: Perhaps you did not incorporated it well. Look at the linked code in my addition

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed but I don't quite understand lines 57-61.

Comment: I made circular rotation of Cue2 (and antipodal cue3) about Cue1  `x = centerx + radius*cos(fi)`